# When is the memory allocated by glBufferData freed?

Tags: opengl

Let's say I allocate memory for a uniform buffer, like so:

```
GLuint length(0x1000);
GLuint myBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &myBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, myBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, length, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

When I am done using the buffer, I would like to make sure that the memory is available again for other buffers. Is it sufficient to call `glDeleteBuffers(1,&myBuffer)` to achieve that? Because my gut feeling tells me there should be a call symmetrical to `glBufferData` for that
(like `glInvalidateBufferData​` in OpenGL 4), but nothing of the kind is mentioned in the documentation for `glBufferData` at all (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferData.xml)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not to be a buzz kill, but container objects such as Vertex Array Objects significantly complicate this discussion.

Normally, when you delete a buffer object two key things happen that allow the memory to be reclaimed:

1. Its name (`GLuint` ID) is freed up for reuse immediately
2. The object is unbound from the ***currently active*** context

#### There is a hidden caveat that needs to be observed:

- The data store is not actually freed until there are *no remaining references* to the object in ***any context***.

When you delete a Vertex Buffer Object that is bound to a Vertex Array Object and that Vertex Array Object is not currently bound, the behavior discussed in bullet point 2 does not occur. What happens is the name is freed up, but the VAO continues to reference both the name (which is now invalid) and the data store (which continues to exist). The memory for the buffer object will not be reclaimed until this Vertex Array Object is deleted, or the binding is changed so that it no longer references the original buffer object.

---

For a more authoritative explanation of the above, I suggest you read **Section 5.1.2** and **Section 5.1.3** of the [OpenGL 4.4 core spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf). I will list the most relevant parts of both below.

#### 5.1.2 Automatic Unbinding of Deleted Objects

> When a buffer, texture, or renderbuffer object is deleted, it is unbound from any bind points it is bound to in the current context, and detached from any attachments of container objects that are bound to the current context, as described for DeleteBuffers, DeleteTextures, and DeleteRenderbuffers. If the object binding was established with other related state (such as a buffer range in BindBufferRange or selected level and layer information in FramebufferTexture or BindImageTexture), that state is not affected by the automatic unbind. Bind points in other contexts are not affected. ***Attachments to unbound container objects, such as deletion of a buffer attached to a vertex array object which is not bound to the context, are not affected and continue to act as references on the deleted object, as described in the following section.***

#### 5.1.3 Deleted Object and Object Name Lifetimes

> [...]
> The underlying storage backing a deleted object **will not be reclaimed** by the GL until ***all references*** to the object from container object attachment points, context binding points, or views **are removed**.

---

**NOTE:** This behavior applies to all container objects in OpenGL, memory is not reclaimed until all references to a resource are eliminated. Familiarizing yourself with the necessary conditions (see: ***5.1.2***) for references to be removed will serve you well in the long-run.

Comment: @Roberto: An interesting way you can cheat the system and immediately free a data store if you do not want to bother tracking down everything that references it would be to do `glBufferData (...)`, supplying a size of 0. This immediately re-allocates the data store for the object with a size of 0, which effectively eliminates the bulk of the storage (memory required to maintain a record of the object will continue to exist, but at least most of the memory will be freed). Of course if you are not careful, this could introduce more issues than it solves; probably not the best of ideas ;)

Answer (score 2):

`glDeleteBuffers` marks the selected buffers for deletion and deallocation, which gets done as soon as no part of OpenGL any longer needs the buffer's data internally. For all practical means `glDeleteBuffers` frees the buffers.