# Memory Management Practices for GLKit under ARC?

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I have written an app which makes use of an OpenGL ES 2.0 scene using GLKit. I am looking now to make sure that I manage all memory associated with the GLKView and GLKViewController.

I have already found the deleteDrawable property on the GLKView which helps to release memory while the scene is not on the screen.

What interests me is the other parts of the GLKit that are using memory - for example the buffers that are setup behind the scenes when using GLKViewController - do these need to be manually released somehow under ARC and if so how ? Also are there any other considerations for memory management under ARC with GLKit ?

Thanks for any insights !

Comment: Considering VBOs create data stores that cannot be freed until all VAOs that reference the VBOs are destroyed or have their references removed, I would say that above and beyond Objective C reference counting you need to implement GL reference counting. Deleting a VBO while it is attached to a VAO will not automatically free the memory, for a more detailed discussion see an [answer I wrote recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639689/when-is-the-memory-allocated-by-glbufferdata-freed/19645105). You will probably want to enacpsulate VAOs and implement your own layer of ref. counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GLKit` is an Objective-C framework. Whenever you are dealing with Objective-C objects, ARC will manage their memory.

So to answer your question, no, you won't need to manually release the memory, provided that you only create Objective-C objects (like `GLKViewController`, `GLKView`, ...).