# How to correctly load/unload textures from video memory?

Tags: java, linux, memory, opengl-es-2.0, jogl

I have a Java OpenGL application - backed by JOGL, running on Linux slitaz 3.2.53-slitaz #4 SMP Europe 2014 i686 GNU/Linux.

OpenGL details:

- Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
- Renderer: Mesa DRI
- Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
- Version: 2.1 Mesa 9.1.3 GL
- Profile: GLProfile[GL2/GL2.hw]

When running loading & deleting textures on the GPU, it crashes after a certain amount of time - proportional to the frequency of loads & unloads, more loads crash sooner etc.

The error given: intel_do_flush_locked failed: No space left on device

In this case I'm:

- Creating a frame buffer, glGenFramebuffers..
- Creating a backing texture, glGenTextures.. glFramebufferTexture2D..
- Binding & drawing into this off-screen frame buffer..
- Deleting the buffer, glDeleteFramebuffers
- Keeping the texture to draw to screen for a few frames
- Deleting the texture, glDeleteTextures

After searching around, I've found sources suggesting that glDeleteTextures doesn't guarantee the free-ing of the VRAM used by the texture, just the ID returned by glGenTextures so it can be reused. For example:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63629/how-to-deallocate-release-delete-of-a-gltexstorage2d

But I've also found articles reporting potential/bugs in the Mesa driver & versions of Lunix that report the same exception: intel_do_flush_locked failed: No space left on device

In conclusion I'm asking:

1. Am I correctly using the OpenGL commands to load & delete textures?
2. Has anyone else had problems with this error & found it to be device/distro related?

Comment: Can you not just reuse the texture?

Comment: I've tried re-using IDs for buffers, textures, renderbuffers & framebuffers. All but re-using framebuffers are working so far, but memory is still being eaten.. Is there something else I have to call to free the resources assigned to the IDs previously?

Comment: You shouldn't see any leaks with what you are doing. The answer you link is correct about the texture memory not necessarily being freed immediately, but if you read the whole answer, it will become clearer what this means. I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269383/opengl-es-1-1-android-does-gl-gldeletetextures-free-video-memory/25278262#25278262, and the message is consistent with the answer you link.

Comment: Reto Koradi is right, the texture should be deleted on the VRAM. It is up to you to manage the direct NIO buffer you use when creating a texture but I think it isn't the culprit in your case.

Comment: All sorted now, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, it was a huge help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was indeed as Reto Koradi suggested in the comments via his answer to [OpenGL es 1.1 - android - does gl.glDeleteTextures free video memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269383/opengl-es-1-1-android-does-gl-gldeletetextures-free-video-memory/25278262#25278262) whereby not detaching textures & render buffers from frame buffers before deletion was keeping them in memory.

To anyone else who is creating off screen frame buffers with textures &/or render buffers, make sure you detach them first! E.g:

- `glBindFramebuffer( GL2ES2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, theFrameBufferID);`
- `glFramebufferTexture2D( GL2ES2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL2ES2.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL2ES2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0);`
- `glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL2ES2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL2ES2.GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL2ES2.GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);`
- `glDeleteFramebuffers.. theFrameBufferID..`
- `glDeleteTextures..`
- `glDeleteRenderbuffers..`
- `glBindFramebuffer( GL2ES2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);`